# Tag Synonym Request - [client-object-model] -> [csom][jsom]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I have suggested synonyms `csom` and `jsom` for tag `client-object-model`.

How this can be reviewed?

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not approve your own suggestions.

I can approve synonyms, but to me [jsom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsom) and [csom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csom) is not synonyms to [client-object-model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-object-model). They are specific types of client object models, but they are not interchangeable with client object model.

[client-object-model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-object-model) is a wider term than the other two, it includes, but is not limited to, both of the other two terms.

I see there is a need for the [jsom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsom) and [csom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csom) tags as well as the [client-object-model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-object-model). It is different languages used for coding in [jsom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsom) and [csom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csom), and depending on your context (SharePoint-hosted app or Provider-hosted app for example) an answer written for [csom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csom) is not applicable in [jsom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsom). Both are needed in many scenarios for users to be able to describe the full context of their question.

You can take a look at the [Active section](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=active&tab=newest) to see relevant uses of tag synonyms used in this site.

Comment: Ok. I thought client object model is master and jsom/csom is part of it. Never thought of using the other way around. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like someone merged it and now it's broken the search for CSOM questions. I just searched for CSOM and got mostly JSOM since it redirected to Client Side Model. These things are not the same and are not equal in functionality.

Comment: Yeah it looks like both jsom and csom now are synonyms to client object model. I guess other parts of the community felt differently than me about it..

Comment: @HughWood I can remove the bindings, but I wonder how the community feels. Do you care to start a new meta question for sorting it out?

Comment: I can, but its like saying SSOM is CSOM, it's a totally different api, with different mappings and methods

Comment: @HughWood, I know (as I say in my answer above it does not make sense to have them as synonyms to me)

Comment: @HughWood, you know what. I will remove the mappings, and then if the issue arises it can always be remapped