# CSOM/JSOM Client Side tags

Tags: discussion

Referring back to this:
[Tag Synonym Request - [client-object-model] -> [csom][jsom]](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1146/tag-synonym-request-client-object-model-csomjsom)

My opinion
This is a stupid suggestion and breaks search.

CSOM is NOT JSOM, they have different functionality they are just built to look the same. The only reason I noticed this was I was trying to look through CSOM questions and found the search completely at the moment as they are currently merged in. Not sure what happened but I predominantly get JSOM results under client object model when I search for CSOM now.

This mapping should be removed as it was put into place by not sure whom.

To clarify the situation

SSOM is Server Side Full Trust Solutions
Sandbox is Server Side Sandbox Solutions
CSOM is Client Side Object Model (.Net)
JSOM is JavaScript Object Model (JS)
REST is the Rest API

These are all separate technologies with different APIs and the tags should remain separate.

Comment: I have always felt that Separating JSOM and CSOM for SharePoint is an error... Actually using JSOM for SharePoint is an error, it should be specifified Javascript CSOM against C# CSOM , as both are client side object models, one for the Javascript API and the other for the C# SDK

Comment: Hi @erin, JSOM is auto generated off of CSOM however expanded from CSOM with extra functionality added from SharePoint. The two are not the same thing at all since it's initial creation, and JSOM has been patched separately to CSOM. JSOM was designed to sit inside of SharePoint and provide a browser client model. This has since gone away and we are left with REST and CSOM which is a far better scenario. They are and should remain different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I too agree with you, I have removed those synonyms, they do not make sense to me either.

If someone disagrees it would be great if they would to answer this question and make their case for why they should be synonyms. This way the community has a way of deciding where this lands.