# Tag synonym request [csom]->[client-side-object-model]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

A [discussion](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/csom-jsom-client-side-tags?lq=1) last year decided that [jsom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsom) and [csom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csom) are not equivalent, and that they are both subsets of the broader [client-object-model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-object-model).

(Whether the distinction is clear to questioners is debatable given that plenty of questions are tagged as [both JavaScript and CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csom+javascript), but that's outside the scope of this discussion.)

However, there's also a [client-side-object-model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-side-object-model) tag floating around. For the sake of consistency, I propose that this tag be made synonymous with [csom].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completely agree. I've merged the tags to [csom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csom).